# Draw a line with horizontal-level text

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

I would like to use the line tool to draw a line between two connectors such that text I put on the line is parallel to the top and bottom of the drawing, instead of being parallel to the line. I would like the text to stay level even if the line changes angles.

I have found instructions on how to make a particular line's text level; it does not do all I want, because any time I change the line orientation, I have to update the text angle.

I have found instructions for setting the text of a shape to be level, but I have been unable to find how they would apply to the line tool.

I'm willing to use a straight-line connector, but haven't found one of those -- the connectors default to drawing horizontal and vertical lines, with right-hand corners when they need to change direction. I would like a line that can be drawn at whatever angle to go from shape A connector to shape B connector.

This used to be easy in earlier versions -- what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the shapesheet editor, select the shape, open the shape's shapesheet, scroll down to the Text Transform section, if it's not there then right-click, insert section and select Text Transform. Now scroll down to the section and change the cell **TxtAngle** and set it to **-ANG360(Angle)**.

Nothing has changed in any version of Visio to stop this working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how to do this. After struggling to find the ShapeSheet editor (in this version of Visio, it is under the "Developer" Main Menu option, which is hidden by default), I finally opened it for the line. But there is no Text Transform section. Should I be looking at somewhere else for a line?

Comment: @rcook My reply has a bit "if it's not there ... "

Comment: When I right-click on the line, I get Show ShapeSheet, cut, copy, paste, group, container, hyperlink..., add comment, edit text, data, and format Shape. Show ShapeSheet gives the same stuff I found off the Developer main menu option, and "Format shape" gives me the same things as the Format Shape panel on the right-hand side of the main window when I just select the line. I'm sorry to be dense, but I just don't see the TxtAngle you refer to. If you've got any other ways to find it, please let me know.

Comment: As a point of interest: a **connector** has a "Text Transform" section in its ShapeSheet, but what I'm dealing with is a **line**. Is there a way to make a Connector run from point to point in a straight line, instead of running on horizontal and vertical axes to get from point to point?

Comment: @rcook. In the Shapesheet editor, if the section is not there then right-click and insert section.